# Knowing $f(x) \to 0$ for $x \to 0$, why is $f(x)/x \to 0$ for $x \to 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let's say, I've found out, that $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0} f(x)= 0$, why is then $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} f(x)/x = 0$? I want to prove, that the function is differentiable at $x=0$, for what I have to show that this limit exists.
$f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is defined as $0$ for $x \leq 0$ und $f(x) = e^{-1/x}/x^n$ for x>0, where I've proven, that in case $x<0$ and x>0 it is differentiable.

Comment: This is not true; take $f(x)=x$.

Answer (score 3):

Your claim is  not always true.

With $$ f(x)=\sin(x)\sin(\frac 1x)$$
you have
$$\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=0$$
because $$|f(x)|\le |\sin(x)|$$
but
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\sin(\frac 1x)$$
does not exist.

For the second, put $ t=\frac 1x $,

So,
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{f(x)}{x}=\lim_{t\to+\infty}t^{n+1}e^{-t}=0$$

In fact, taking logarithm, we get
$$\lim_{+\infty}\ln(t^{n+1}e^{-t})=$$
$$\lim_{+\infty}\Bigl(t((n+1)\frac{\ln(t)}{t}-1)\Bigr)=$$
$$+\infty(0-1)=-\infty$$

Comment: For the second: Is there another way besides substitution?

Comment: The exponential is faster than the polynomial near infinity.

Comment: That's not working as argument in our lectures :(

Comment: @Mathpiano This is an usual limit.

Comment: @Mathpiano Take the logarithm to get a well-known limit.

Comment: I am thankful for your help, but could you be more specific, how exactly I have to take the logarithm?

Comment: @Mathpiano Ok, look now, i just added some lines.

Answer (score 0):

Not true.

Take $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$.
Then,
as $x \to 0$,
$f(x) \to 0$
but
$\dfrac{f(x)}{x}
=\dfrac1{\sqrt{x}}
\to \infty
$.